# Is AIDE supporting for Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just want to link my app to Firebase, Is it possible through IDE( An Integrated Development Environment) android app.

Does IDE support Firebase Phone authentication?

Answer (score 1):

1. With Android Studio, you have the inbuilt feature to link your app with the firebase. With other IDE, you need to manually add JSON file (Downloadble from your project in Firebase console) to the project. Please refer [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
2. There's no relation between IDE and Firebase Phone authentication. In other words, you can develop [Firebase Phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) through IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I referred the Firebase docs, with the JSON file manually we can add, i didn't tried yet, i will back after trying with it. @Sethuraman Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use.But Android studio IDE is best supports Firebase authentication.
refer this link for integrating firebase ana android studio
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

refer this site for information about how to integrate firebase and our application

https://auth0.com/blog/firebase-phone-authentication/

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. I know Android studio supporting for Firebase Phone Authentication. Other than Android studio like AIDE, Sketchware apps. If so please tell me the process.